# How do I implement a Floodlight tag into an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, tags, tracking

A client is asking me to insert a Floodlight tag into an Objective-C programmed iPhone app that is ready for submission to the App Store.

I did some Googling, and couldn't find anything about how to do this (it seems like you can you only add Floodlight tags via Javascript, but I'm not too sure). Can you do this, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can create an offscreen UIWebView and invoke the appropriate javascript with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.  Not a good solution, but if javascript is required it may be your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding a `UIWebView` right off the bat for this, you could try using `NSURLConnection` to request the URL normally inserted with the Floodlight iframe. It seems that unless the contents of the iframe (which should just be a transparent GIF) need to interact with the host page, simply performing and receiving the request should fulfill the purposes of tracking. Check the ToS, though, to see if they have any stipulations about this.